# Setting Sql Query Output to a list in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql

I'm working on a project for work, and this issue has been holding me up all day. My database consists of 9 Columns that are used to identify a specific row based on user inputs and 7 columns that contain the relevant data for that user given their inputs match the first 9 columns of the row match. This may not be the most efficient way of structure the database, but it's an artifact of the prototype and I'd really rather not change it. I have a SQL Query that selects the correct row based on the user's inputs, and now I want to assign a variable to each of the remaining 7 columns (called OA5,OA10,OA15,OA20,OA25,OA30,and OALife), so that I can graph them for the user. I haven't been able to figure out how to do this given the way I have my sql query structured below.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cs_test website %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [OARiskData$] WHERE Age = @myAge AND Sex = @mySex AND Race = @myRace AND FamHx = @myFamRisk AND OccEx = @myOccRisk AND HxInj = @myHxInj AND BMI = @myBMI AND UnderCost = 1 AND RiskProg = 0">


     <SelectParameters>

        <asp:Parameter Name="myBMI" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="myAge" Type="String" />
        <asp:FormParameter DefaultValue="" Name="mySex" FormField="inputSex" Type="String" />
        <asp:FormParameter DefaultValue="" Name="myRace" FormField="inputRace" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="myFamRisk" Type="String" />
        <asp:FormParameter DefaultValue="" Name="myOccRisk" FormField="occRisk" Type="String" />
        <asp:FormParameter DefaultValue="" Name="myHxInj" FormField="hxInj" Type="String" />


     </SelectParameters>


</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Why are u using SqlDataSource - are u binding data to some control? Or you simple need to repetitive data into .NET variables? (btw what language are u using?)

Comment: I'm using Visual Basic. I'm very much a beginner at this and won't be doing much web development beyond this project. SqlDataSource was the way I found to display the correct row of data, but there's really no reason I'm using it besides the fact that it worked.

Comment: what exactly is your problem? do you want to display the data in a html table or in a listbox? what do you mean with 'assign a variable to each column'?

Comment: I want to assign the value of the OA5 column to a variable. Ultimately, I want to create a bar graph where OA5, OA10, OA15, etc will each have a bar that is the height of the value in that column.

Comment: can you show the code of your bar graph control? If you need the values in the code behind file you better don't use the SqlDataSource control. This is only useful when you can bind the values directly (e.g. GridView, DetailsView, FormView control).